# using linq and c# to create a nested list object from a flat list object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question. It's about linq in combination with c#.
I want to create a tree structure from a flatten structure in a pre defined object structure.

The following code which I've got work, but both are not exactly what i want.

In linq:

```
     var result = listAgenderingen.GroupBy(records => records.Agnnummer)
                    .Select(group => new { AgnNummer = group.Key, Items = group.ToList()}).ToList();
```

the issue is that this does not result in the object I want. 
So I've rewritten this to the following code

```
            List<string> test = listAgenderingen.Select(x => x.Agnnummer).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in test)
        {
            List<Agendering> listAgendering = listAgenderingen.Where(agend => agend.Agnnummer == item).OrderBy(ord => ord.Agnnummer).ToList();
            AgnAgendering AgnAgendering = new AgnAgendering() {AgnNummer =item, Agenderingen = listAgendering };
        }
```

this code actually works correct. but for 200000 records, it's taking a lot of time while the original linq takes a few seconds.

my question is can the linq be rewritten so it will create or convert to the richt object?

the structure of the classes:

```
    public class Agendering
{
    public int AgnID { get; set; }
    public string Agnnummer { get; set; }
}

   public class AgnAgendering
{
    public string AgnNummer { get; set; }
    public List<Agendering> Agenderingen { get; set; }
}
```

I hope someone has a sollution.

Comment: Your properties naming makes it absolutely unreadable and unclear. I look at this for 30 seconds and still can't remember what are primary and foreign keys here, and what result do you expect.

Comment: On the second version, why do you do `.OrderBy(ord => ord.Agnnummer)` ? You've already filtered by `agend.Agnnummer == item`, so all values are the same. What does the sort do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
 var result = listAgenderingen.GroupBy(records => records.Agnnummer)
                .Select(group => new AgnAgendering { AgnNummer = group.Key, Agenderingen = group.ToList()}).ToList();
```

Comment: Almost. I do not want the declaration var result = 
this should me a 
List<AgnAgendering>    = listAgenderingen.GroupBy......
So I'm missing a conversion for this part

Comment: @user3507211 - `result` *is* a  `List<AgnAgendering>`. You can just replace `var` with `List<AgnAgendering>` - it's the same in this case.

Comment: the problem is that I cant get the linq result to be converted to my objects.

Comment: @user3507211 - You don't have to convert anything. I'm using `new AgnAgendering` ... `.ToList()`, so result is already of type `List<AgnAgendering>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your properties naming makes it absolutely unreadable and unclear.

Assuming that you have a flat structure like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

and you want a tree-like structure:

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public TreeItem Parent { get; set; }
    public List<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }

    public TreeItem(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Children = new List<TreeItem>();
    }

    public TreeItem(int id, TreeItem parent) : this(id)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

You can do most optimally in `O(n)` using `Dictionary`:

```
Item[] items = ...;

Dictionary<int, TreeItem> result = new Dictionary<int, TreeItem>();

foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(x => x.ParentID ?? -1))
{
    TreeItem current; 

    if (item.ParentID.HasValue)
    {
        TreeItem parent = result[item.ParentID]; // guaranteed to exist due to order
        current = new TreeItem(item.ID, parent);            
        parent.Children.Add(current);
    } else {
        current = new TreeItem(item.ID);
    }
}

TreeItem[] treeItems = result.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: I also thought this is what the OP wanted, and they did say "tree structure". But the code suggests it's just GroupBy, and on the OP's code, there is no nesting - just one level (`AgnAgendering` has a list of `Agendering`).